# Amazon Sagemaker pricing of cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I've gone through the pricing page of Sagemaker at https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/. I could not find the information on how it charges the cost of emitting logs to cloudwatch. Does the price listed include the price of emitting logs or are they charged according to Cloudwatch log pricing separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All AWS Services that uses Cloudwatch you will be charged according to Cloudwatch log pricing.

Comment: Since we have been sending more logs to Cloudwatch, we are seeing an increase in the price as well.

Comment: That’s it. You can set the log in the training job to False using the python Sagemaker api, or tells CloudWatch to erase data periodically (you still have to pay per CloudWatch ingestion).